# password_verify() logging in all the time

Tags: php, codeigniter, bcrypt

Using codeigniter hashed my password with BCRYPT, seems that everytime I login I redirect to the success page.  So I am figuring password verify is not working, even if I enter the incorrect login it still redirects, does not throw the form_validation errors either.

I used the documentation to set it up along with the guides on SO. Will eventually go to Ion Auth but want to know how to fix this. As I am still learning code igniter mvc.

Model

```
class user_model extends CI_Model{

public function register($encrypt_pass){

$data = array(

'name'=> $this->input->post('name'),
'email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
'password'=>password_hash($encrypt_pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT)

);

return $this->db->insert('customers',$data);

}

public function login($username,$password){

//validate the inputs from form
$this->db->where('username',$username);

$query = $this->db->get('customers'); //customers is the table

$result = $query->row_array();

if(!empty($result) && password_verify($password, $result['password'])){


  return $result;

}

else{

return "false";
}

}

}
```

Controller

```
public function login()
  {

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

if($this->form_validation->run()=== FALSE){
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('users/login',$data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
else {

//Getting username
$username = $this->input->post('Username');

 //Getting and ecrypting password

$password = $this->input->post('Password');//password hashed

$user_id = $this->user_model->login($result);



//checking for user/pass correct will set session if so
 if($user_id){

$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin','You are now logged in');
redirect('posts');
 }

// If combo is incorrect will redirect
else{

$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin','Login Failed, Please Try 
Again');
redirect('users/login');

}

}

}

}
```

Comment: You tried this? `$this->session->set_userdata($user_id);`

Comment: Add `password_verify()` function code in your question.

Comment: where would I put this in my if($user_id) statement? @Roshan

Comment: @DanishAli it is in my model.

Comment: But implementation of `password_verify()` is not included in your question right now. And I think issue is here `if(!empty($result) && password_verify($password, $result['password']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working login code, there are many ways how to do it, it's just an example.

**ON YOUR MODEL**

*Create a function that will check/get the username's password.*

```
public function _getUserPassword($user_name){

    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('PASSWORD');
    $this->db->from('tbl_user');
    $this->db->where('USER_NAME', $user_name);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){

        foreach($query->result_array() as $field_name => $field_value){
            $data = $field_value;
        }

        return $data;
    }
    else{

        return false;
    }
}
```

> I've seen your's just selecting it.

*We need to use that `_getUserPassword` function on we call it `verify` function*

```
    function verify($username, $password){

    $data = array();

    $userNameExists = $this->_getUserPassword($username);

    if(password_verify($password, $userNameExists['PASSWORD'])){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_user AS user');
        $this->db->where('USER_NAME', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){

            foreach($query->result_array() as $field_name => $field_value){
                $data = $field_value;
            }

            return $data;
        }
        else{

            return false;
        }
    }
    else{

        return false;
    }
}
```

> So if the verification is success it will return the data to your controller, *Let's use your controller.*

`Let's assume that you changed the models`

**ON YOUR CONTROLLER**

```
public function login()
   {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()=== FALSE){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/login',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}else {

    //Getting username
    $username = $this->input->post('Username');
    //Getting and ecrypting password
    $password = $this->input->post('Password');
    $user_id = $this->user_model->verify($username,$password);

    //checking for user/pass correct will set session if so
    if($user_id){

    $this->session->set_userdata('user_loggedin','You are now logged in');
    redirect('posts');

    }else{
   //DO NOT SET USER DATA SESSION HERE UNLESS IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY LOGGED IN.

    redirect('users/login');

    }
  }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this it works, I still do not see what I was missing as i was pulling the password hash from the database and comparing it with the one from the form.Could you explain to me what I was missing / or why it didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think while you are getting the result of getting user's password, you used `$query->row_array()` instead of `$query->result_array()` store it in an `array()` variable and you can parse the data as `$data['ColumName']` also the simplest way of checking if your `$result` variable instead of checking if it's empty, consider using `$query->num_rows() > 0` AND ALSO, Never set session when login fails!

Answer (score 0):

where you are checking that password is matching or not.
 try this in your controller.after user check.

```
if($user>0){
  if (password_verify($this->input->post('Password'), $user_id['password'])) {
//success message
}
else{
//error message.password is invalid
}
```

Comment: I am checking this in the model? so I would write the password_verify function in the model and controller? I am just really confused.

Comment: just use this function in your controller.